# Websockets python

Tags: python, websocket

I have some code in NodeJs:

```
var Pusher = require('pusher-client');

var pusher = new Pusher('c0eef4118084f8164bec65e6253bf195', {
    encrypted: true,
    wsPort: 443,
    wssPort: 443,
    host: 'notifier.bitskins.com'
});

pusher.connection.bind('connected', function() {
    // connected to realtime updates 
    console.log(" -- connected to websocket");
});
```

How can I do it in python?

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow the docs of [python-socketio-client](https://python-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/client.html#the-socket-io-client)

You can use `socketio.AsyncClient()` similarly to node.js async client.